# How to give a recourse from one user to another user in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

For the sake of making this understandable I use a simplified version to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

The platform has 10 books (book 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10).

The platform has 2 users (user A and B).

The user can have unlimited books, even duplicated once. For example User A would have book 3, 4 times.

The user can't buy or get books by their self!
A user can give books to others, max 5 books per person.

So User A give 5 books to user B, that's what there should happen, but how?

**This is what I got so far.**

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, through: :user_books
  has_many :user_books
```

Book model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :user_books
  has_many :user_books
```

UserBook model:

```
class UserBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
```

To add books in my show model of a user:

```
  %h2 Add Books
  .field.item
    - Book.all.each do |book|
      =link_to add_book_user_path(@user, book) do
        .book
          = book.title
```

Routes:

```
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update] do
    member { post 'add_book'}
  end
```

Users controller:

```
def add_book
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  @user.update_attribute(book_ids << @book.id)
end
```

I should so something of a create action, updating will not add something right?

**I get this error:**

> No route matches [GET] "/users/3/add_book.1"

It seems strange there is add_book.1 instead of add_book/1 (1 is the ID of the book).

Any help would be much appreciated!
Many thanks,
Chris!

Comment: Thats' indeed weird..
Can you check if the following works for you in the routes?

    post 'users/:id/add_book' => 'users#add_book'

Comment: also, maybe dropping the .book will do - the add_book_user_path helper should generate the url with book's id as a url parameter

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, the first route doesn't seems to work, what should I put into the add_book_user_path.helper.rb?

Comment: Hey changing post to get in the routes will get me to the right method, but I get this error.

undefined local variable or method `book_ids' for #<UsersController:0x007f8280242548> Did you mean? virtues_url virtue_url

@user is defined right?

Comment: you shouldn't create your own helper. just use the rails defaults. you can learn more from here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: what about '@user.books << @book'

Comment: please upvote if you it helped you. Thanks

Comment: Hey I finnaly got it working, but it's litterly a complete rewrite that would be to much for 1 comment! Thx for the help.